# find max value in one row and return column name

Tags: r

This is my data frame. I want to get the highest number in row 3 and return column name i.e result should be "Height"

```
tt<-"Rows    Weight      Age        Height
    Cats -0.7289964  0.2194702 -2.4674780 
    Dogs  1.0889353  0.3167629 -0.9208548 
    Rats -0.6374692 -1.7249049  0.6567313 
    Mice -0.1348642  0.4507473 -1.7309010"

data <- read.table(text=tt, header=T)
```

Comment: Age does not have the highest value. Do you mean the highest absolute value?

Comment: No my apologies should be height. What I need to return is the height. In other words what is the largest number for rats which is the height.

Comment: runs       walks        cycles
paul 33333 44444 3
john 3333 6599999 555555
mike 33          1         11111111
jim 43 2 15
Let me rephrase how do I find what mike does the most in terms of mileage answer should b cycles 11111111

Answer (score 3):

As @G5W noted, Age in the third row does not have the highest value but the highest absolute value:

```
colnames(df)[max.col(abs(df[3, ]), ties.method = "first")]
```

If you are really interested in the highest value, then:

```
colnames(df)[max.col(df[3, ], ties.method = "first")]
```

Or if you prefer a `tidyverse` solution, returning the column with the highest absolute value:

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  filter(rowid == 3) %>%
  gather(col, val, Weight:Height) %>%
  filter(abs(val) == max(abs(val))) %>%
  select(-rowid, -val)
```

Returning the column with the highest value:

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  filter(rowid == 3) %>%
  gather(col, val, Weight:Height) %>%
  filter(val == max(val)) %>%
  select(-rowid, -val)
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "       Weight      Age        Height
Cats -0.7289964  0.2194702 -2.4674780 
                 Dogs  1.0889353  0.3167629 -0.9208548 
                 Rats -0.6374692 -1.7249049  0.6567313 
                 Mice -0.1348642  0.4507473 -1.7309010", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

colnames(df)[max.col(df[3, ], ties.method = "first")] returns an error

> colnames(test)[max.col(test[3, ], ties.method = "first")]
>   [1] NA
>   Warning message:
>   In max.col(test[3, ], ties.method = "first") : NAs introduced by coercion